# Check status of batch job in init container

Tags: kubernetes

My requirement is to start a pod when a particular batch job is completed.

Batch job yaml file

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: topics
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: topics
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        name: topics
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.0
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - {{.Values.KafkaTopics}}
```

2 Deployment yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: opp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: opp

      initContainers:
      - name: init
        image: busybox
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'until nc -z someservice:8093; do echo waiting for init; sleep 2; done;']
```

Init container fine when I am checking for some service to be up. Not able to figure it out for batch job.

Answer (score 1):

> start a pod

What you have described with a `Deployment` is a **deployment of a service**, not only *starting* a pod.

### Watch status of Kubernetes objects

> when a particular batch job is completed.

If you want to watch Kubernetes objects and do actions depending on change of status of a particular object, you need to interact with the Kubernetes API server.

**Use a Kubernetes client**

The easiest way to interact with the Kubernetes API, especially for *watch* is to use a pre-built client, e.g. [client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) or [kubernetes-client Java](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java).

**Use the Kubernetes REST API**

Alternatively you can use the [Kubernetes REST API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/) directly.

**API Authentication and Authorization**

Beware that you should use a *Service Account* for authentication and set properly RBAC rules for authorization.

### Kafka Consumer

An alternative solution, since your `Job` hints that you are using Kafka. Your `Job` could publish an event on Kafka, and you can have a *Kafka Consumer* to *subscribe* and act upon those events. But if the consumer should *deploy* a service on an event, it also need an *Service Account* to interact with the Kubernetes API server.